# Ошибка при компиляции python файла pyInstaller'ом

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Я написал голосового помощника и решил скомпилить его при помощи `pyInstaller`, но при открытии выводится ошибка и консоль моментально закрывается. Что делать?
Руководствовался [этим](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YeS755SPSI8) и [этим](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CgCJwDjm_Cw) видео (Хауди Хо)
[image: Ошибка в консоли]

Comment: No module named "pyttsx3.drivers"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pip install pyttsx3
```

Если не поможет попробуйте указать эти библиотеки напрямую

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import=pyttsx3.drivers --hidden-import=pyttsx3.drivers.dummy --hidden-import=pyttsx3.drivers.espeak --hidden-import=pyttsx3.drivers.nsss --hidden-import=pyttsx3.drivers.sapi5 Имяфайла.py
```

Comment: Спасибо! `pyttsx3` уже был установлен, а вот 2 вариант помог!